# How to add users to Linux through a shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script, users, password, group

The shell script that I have to write has to create new users and automatically assign them to groups. This is my code so far:

```
echo -n "Enter the username: "
read text
useradd $text
```

I was able to get the shell script to add the new user (I checked the `/etc/passwd` entry). However, I have tried and I am not able to get a passwd (entered by the user) to the newly created user before. If anyone could help me assign a password to the newly created user it would be of much help.

Comment: Have you tried `man useradd`?

Comment: Also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714915/using-the-passwd-command-from-within-a-shell-script where use of `passwd --stdin` is covered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Output from  "man 1 passwd":

```
--stdin
      This option is used to indicate that passwd should read the new
      password from standard input, which can be a pipe.
```

So to answer your question, use the following script:

```
echo -n "Enter the username: "
read username

echo -n "Enter the password: "
read -s password

adduser "$username"
echo "$password" | passwd "$username" --stdin
```

I used `read -s` for the password, so it won't be displayed while typing.

**Edit:** For Debian/Ubuntu users `-stdin` won't work. Instead of `passwd` use `chpasswd`:

```
  echo $username:$password | chpasswd
```

Comment: On my host (Linux Mint) the `--stdin` does not work: `passwd: unrecognized option '--stdin'`

Comment: Alternative is to use `read -rs newpassword; useradd -p $(md5pass "$newpassword") $username`

Comment: The '--stdin' also does not work on my host. I tried the 'chpasswd' but that also does not seem to work. Any other advice

Comment: which OS do you use?

Comment: I use QEMU Linux.

Comment: aren't you ask to enter the password when executing `adduser`?

Comment: With the updated version it works. Instead of creating a new group with the name of the username, is there a way to assign the user to a specific already created group?

Comment: I have resolved the issue by adding usermod -a -G "groupname" "username". This assigns the user to a secondary group.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter username: "
read username
useradd "$username"
echo "temp4now" | passwd --stdin "$username"
chage -d 0 "$username"
```

Comment: A bit of explanation (esp. for lines -1 and -2) would be quite nice.